# What are limitations on using third-party(CocoaPods) libraries?

Tags: ios

**Background**
- I am backend Software engineer for many years.
- I am starting to learn iOS development to build a project based on an idea
- I came across [cocoapods](http://cocoapods.org/) which is used to pull in awesome third-party libraries into your own project

**Then what is the problem?**
- when building for mobile devices, resources are really critical. Example, space, memory, etc.
- I wanted to learn if using thirdparty libraries has some implications (I guess not since most of developers use it). But being new to this space I am confused?

**What I want?**
- Is it okay for a project to include multiple third=party libraries? What about space and memory issues.
- Doesn't it increases the size(space needed) of the project?

- What are the recommendations?

P.S. Apologies for not asking for a programming question, but did not find a better place to ask this question.

Answer (score 2):

Using 3rd party libraries may or may not be any more of a problem then writing it all yourself. I have a large, sophisticated iOS app that uses nearly two-dozen 3rd party libraries without issue.

There are apps that use no 3rd party libraries and their app is almost too big for the App Store.

The issue isn't code, it is resources like images, video, and sound files.

Don't worry about it until you actually have a problem. The size of your project is irrelevant. The final size of your IPA is relevant.

BTW - CocoaPods is irrelevant to your question.